# Stop awaiting remaining promises if one returns sentinel value

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function validateTables() that validates that data exists in several tables using a call (per table) to an async helper function queryTable() that queries the api. To pass validation, data must exist in every table. If a table is empty, the helper function will return false. I currently have the set of calls in a Promise.all() that checks the resulting array for any false values. For performance, I would rather stop awaiting the resolution of any remaining promises if and when a promise resolves to false. Promise.race() and .all() don't work because they are concerned with *when* or *if* a promise resolves, not the returned value. Can I do this without losing the parallel processing of the async functions?

Generalized functions:

```js
async queryTable(query, params) {
        try {
            returnData = []
            for await (const returnItem of api.executeQuery(query, params)){
                returnData.push(returnItem)
            }

            if (returnData.length > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch (err) {
            throw new Error(`${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
        }
    }

async validateTables() {
       const allDataExists = await Promise.all([
                this.queryTable(query, params),
                this.queryTable(query2, params2),
                this.queryTable(query3, params3),
                // and so on for several more
            ])
            if (!allDataExists.includes(false)) {
                return 'OK'
            }
            return 'Invalid'
    }
```

Comment: I think a decent way of doing this would be to use a shared data structure and await a single promise that watches the data structure for a specific end condition (like a failure flag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The promise returned by `Promise.all` will reject as soon as *any* of the containing promises reject. With that in mind, you could throw the sentinel value instead of returning it, and simply check for that in a try/catch around the `await`.

```
async queryTable(query, params) {
    try {
        returnData = []
        for await (const returnItem of api.executeQuery(query, params)){
            returnData.push(returnItem)
        }

        if (returnData.length > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        throw false;
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw new Error(`${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
    }
}

async validateTables() {
    try {
        const allDataExists = await Promise.all([
            this.queryTable(query, params),
            this.queryTable(query2, params2),
            this.queryTable(query3, params3),
            // and so on for several more
        ])
    } catch(e) {
        if(e instanceof Error) throw e
        return 'Invalid'
    }
    return 'OK'
}
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you. For others reading this, a note - if throwing a value besides false, in my case I decided to throw the table name for logging, it throws it as an instance of Error. So the handling - `if(e instanceof Error)` - has to be moved to the catch block of the query function instead of the validate function or everything will be a new `throw e` instead of `return 'Invalid'`